# FMOD gapless loop and sequence playback

Tags: c#, loops, sequence, fmod

I started using FMOD library, because I need to play sounds without gaps in C# application (both one sound in a loop and many sounds in a sequence). Can anyone show me the correct way to do it? I tried make something based on examples, but it's not working as I would like it to work. 
Firstly, when I try to set if the sound is looped, while it's playing,

```
if (value)  
    sound1.setMode(FMOD.MODE.LOOP_NORMAL);
else 
    sound1.setMode(FMOD.MODE.LOOP_OFF);
```

nothing is going on. It only works fine, when I set th mode, before I start playback.

The second issue is: how can I be notified that the sound has reached the end? I tried to do it this way:

```
channel.setCallback(eofCallback);
```

where eofCallback is a reference to SoundEndCallback

```
    private FMOD.RESULT SoundEndCallback(IntPtr channelraw, FMOD.CHANNEL_CALLBACKTYPE type, IntPtr commanddata1, IntPtr commanddata2)
    {
        FMOD.RESULT result;

        if (type == FMOD.CHANNEL_CALLBACKTYPE.END)
        {
            //logic here
        }
        return FMOD.RESULT.OK;
    }
```

But this callback is reached only when I manually invoke stop() on channel, not when the track ends.

Or eventually do you know any other library that would give me easily what I need? I chose FMOD, because it's quite popular, but I don't like its oldschool C++-like way of coding (no events, no exceptions, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the loop mode of a sound at runtime use Channel::setMode, Sound::setMode is like setting the defaults for any channels played from that sound (it won't affect currently playing sounds).

As for Channel::setCallback, make sure you are calling System::update regularly to have the callbacks fire for events like the sound playing to the end.

Answer (score 1):

And I have teh answer for my second question: to get notified you have to firstly set callback as mentioned before, and after that you've got to use System.update() method (it must be called periodically in a loop). This is a kind of polling,